# How to add datetime Field to + 1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In My stored procedure I have a StartDate and EndDate fields are in Varchar(10)

```
@StartDate Varchar(10),
@EndDate Varchar(10)
```

I am giving an input from the UI for start date 03/01/2013 and 03/04/2013

For end date I need to Add one day +  that is if my EndDate is 03/04/2013 I need to Update that to 03/05/2013..

Thanks

Comment: Check your question. After update also you mentioned the same result. You mean that 03/05/2013?

Comment: Have you looked into using **DATEADD** together with **CONVERT**?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the date datatype for this?  Then you could simply use the dateadd() function to add one day.

Comment: Never ever under any circumstances store dates as varchar. This serios design flaw needs to be immdeiately fixed or you willhave bad data in the field. In over 30 years of qerying databases from many different sources, I have never seen one yet that used varchar for dates that did not have serious data integrity problems with that information.

Answer (score 6):

If this is a new stored procedure (or not any other codes using it), best thing is to change your variables to Date type. Because `if you comparing data by date` *you should compare* `Dates not varchar values`.

If you `CAN` change the variable type then you can add a day using `DATEADD()` function as below.

```
--if @enddate is a date type
select @enddate = dateadd(day,1,@enddate)
```

If you `CANNOT` change variable types, you better pass them in `ISO format` (ie; `yyyymmdd`) because your current string format is culture specific and query could fail in a server with a different culture.

```
--date pass as yyyymmdd (not culture specific)
select @enddate = convert(varchar(10), 
                      dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, @enddate)), 101)

--date pass as mm/dd/yyyy (US culture)
select @enddate = convert(varchar(10), 
                      dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, @enddate,101)), 101)
```

Answer (score 3):

`SET @EndDate = DATEADD (d, 1, CAST(@StartDate AS datetime))` gives you the answer as a `datetime`. You can then convert back to a varchar if you need:

`SET @EndDate = CAST(DATEADD (d, 1, CAST(@StartDate AS datetime)) AS varchar(10))`

Comment: This is giving me an error when i am trying to do the same thing.. Converstion of a varchar type to date time date time data type resulted out of range value.